# VB.net to c# error and i dont understand why

Tags: c#, .net

Hello i tried converting this but i dont seem to figure out why.

Im working on a external log in for my forum

```
public override bool isLoggedIn(System.Net.CookieContainer cookies)
{
    if ((cookies.GetCookies(new Uri(url)).Item(defaultCookieName) != null)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but it gives me this annoying error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'CookieCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'CookieCollection' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: try `cookies.GetCookies(new Uri(url))[defaultCookieName]` and let us know if that fixes it

Comment: "Item" is the placeholder in the MSDN documentation for the indexer of the class.  The one you use without a name and [square brackets].  Let the Intellisense popup help you fall in the pit of success.

Answer (score 1):

C# syntax for this is

```
cookies.GetCookies(..)[defaultCookieName]
```